# With and without use of Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Please help me to figure out the best solution. I need to handle some event and validate and process. I have implemented and it is working fine with Approach 1 mentioned below.  But I have got a review comment to use Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(). But I don't understand what is the advantage of using it? Could any one help me to understand on approach 2 mentioned below.

```
Approach 1:
===========
@Path("/webhook")
class A {
    @Path("/order")
    public void consumeMessage(String body) {
        POEvent event = objectMapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<POEvent>() {
        handleEvent(event);
    }
    public void handleEvent(POEvent po) {
        //validation on this event
        processEvent(po);
    }
    processEvent(POEvent poEvent) {
        //call external system 
    }
}
```

Here is the suggestion i have got.

```
Approach 2:
===========
@Path("/webhook")
class A {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    @Path("/order")
    public void consumeMessage(String body) {
        POEvent event = objectMapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<POEvent>() {
        handleEvent(event);
    }
    public void handleEvent(POEvent po) {
        //validation on this event
        executor.submit(() -> {
            processEvent(po);
        });
    }
    processEvent(POEvent poEvent) {
         //call external system 
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Response consumeMessage(String body)` - your code does not see to return a `Response`  Assuming your **real** code does, it then using `ExecutorService#submit` will run the code in another thread and return immediately - whether this is good or not is a different matter

Comment: I don't see why an **ExecutorService** would be needed here, unless you expect to have long running tasks.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have corrected it by changing it to void as return type. I just used small snippet of code here not the real code.

Comment: Ask the reviewer why. There might be a good reason, or the reviewer might be wrong. But we have no context, son we can't tell.

Comment: Case might be that review thinks that the processEvent is either a time consuming or a optional event which should not obstruct the overall flow like a mail sending task.